# how to get current colour of FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, colors, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I have FloatingActionButton in my App:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOj2C.jpg
witch have configuration in according with image from link above.

In my app user can change the colour of this FloatingActionButton by clicking on this button.

```
 fabUP = findViewById(R.id.fab_dwn);
    fabUP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Saving mode", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("SAVE", null).show();
            fabDOWN.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.FLOAT_dark_GREEN)));
            fabUP.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.FLOAT_bright_RED)));
            SAVE=true;
        }
    });
```

I would like to save the colour of this button on onSaveInstanceState method and set on onRestoreInstanceState method.

```
   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //here I would like to save the colour of my FloatingActionButton
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
       //and here I would like to set the colour of my FloatingActionButton
    }
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
fab.getBackgroundTintList()
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    
    if(fabUP!=null) 
    { 
        outState.putString("fabUP", fabUP.getSupportBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()+""); 
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        fabUP.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(savedInstanceState.getString("fabUP"))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save color on onSaveInstanceState method you can  use like

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //here I would like to save the colour of my FloatingActionButton
    outstate.putParcelable("fab_up", fabUP.getBackgroundTintList())
    outstate.putParcelable("fab_down", fabDOWN.getBackgroundTintList())
}
```

To Restore the color you can use

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
       //and here I would like to set the colour of my FloatingActionButton
        fabDOWN.setBackgroundTintList(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("fab_down"));
        fabUP.setBackgroundTintList(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("fab_up"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Vishnu your proposition is the most optimal. Thanks.